# How to get active tabbed or floating document in document group (DevExpress WPF mvvm)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

It's me again :) 
I making global `Escape` shortcut for application. Its implementation from global hook and send close message in `DomainModelContext`(main `UserControl` from scaffolding wizard). I trying bad way - use code-behind. 
I use  `DockLayoutManager.DockController.Close(DockLayoutManager.ActiveDockItem)` 
for close tab, but its method close everything including LayoutPanel :(
How  i do implement Close active document with tabbed and floating docs.

Under the document, I mean View inherited from SingleObjectViewModel or those that were manually undocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to accomplish your task is to handle the CloseMessage at the View Model level (DomainModelContextViewModel,  I believe).
At this level you can use the API of the [IDocumentManagerService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressMvvmIDocumentManagerServicetopic):

```
void OnCloseMessage() {
    var activeDocument = DocumentManagerService.ActiveDocument;
    if(activeDocument != null)
        activeDocument.Close();
}
```

Note: the specific implementation of the `IDocumentManagerService` ([TabbedDocumentUIService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument18173)) should be registered within the `DomainModelContextView`.